# htaccess not denying access to file

Tags: .htaccess, basic-authentication

I've got a .htaccess file at the root of my directory that looks like the below.  The clients.php file is granting access to users in the htgroups file which are NOT in the admins group.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www......com/dts/$1 [R,L]

AuthGroupFile /usr/local/..../htgroup
AuthType Basic
Require group producers

<Files clients.php>
  Require group admins
</Files>
```

It is requiring the people to authenticate and be in that producers group (all admins are also in producers) but it's letting people not on the admins line open the clients.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the directives matter. Since the first require is applied globally, that's the one that's going to be used. You can try switching the order:

```
AuthGroupFile /usr/local/..../htgroup
AuthType Basic
<Files clients.php>
  Require group admins
</Files>
Require group producers
```

or adding it as a negative match:

```
AuthGroupFile /usr/local/..../htgroup
AuthType Basic
<Files clients.php>
  Require group admins
</Files>
<FilesMatch (?<!clients.php)>
  Require group producers
</FilesMatch>
```